# Webpage Jquery dropdown buttons not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make buttons for a webpage that you can hover the mouse over and a 'drop down like' box will appear next to it with links and information.

Here's a link to what it looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/kvbvLy4d/

After implementing this into the webpage I had the buttons stopped working. This is what I have:

(I have removed irrelevant code to minimize length - Let me know if you need me to post the full script)

**html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
    <script src="resources/scripts/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#box, #content").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $("#content").slideDown(); //.show();
})
.on("mouseleave", function() {
    if (!$("#content").is(":hover"))
    $("#content").fadeOut(); //hide();
});

$("#box1, #content1").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $("#content1").slideDown(); //.show();
})
.on("mouseleave", function() {
    if (!$("#content1").is(":hover"))
    $("#content1").fadeOut(); //hide();
});

$("#box2, #content2").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $("#content2").slideDown(); //.show();
})
.on("mouseleave", function() {
    if (!$("#content2").is(":hover"))
    $("#content2").fadeOut(); //hide();
});
</script>

<div id="buttons">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="content">content here</div>
  <div id="box1"></div>
  <div id="content1">content here</div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
  <div id="content2">content here</div>
</div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**css**

(same for each box and content div apart from position)

```
#box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 23vw;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: blue;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 23vw;
  left: 11vw;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

Any help, better ways to do this or a link to a question that specifically answers this would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your fiddle works for me.

Comment: Sorry that might not have been very clear :p The fiddle isn't the problem, its when I try to apply it in my webpage. The code I posted is from my page.

Comment: Try commenting out certain assets.  This one in particular `<script src="resources/scripts/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Still doesn't work, would the full code be any help?

Comment: Why do you have multiple jQuery versions on that page?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
    <script src="resources/scripts/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
$("#box, #content").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $("#content").slideDown(); //.show();
})
.on("mouseleave", function() {
    if (!$("#content").is(":hover"))
    $("#content").fadeOut(); //hide();
});

$("#box1, #content1").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $("#content1").slideDown(); //.show();
})
.on("mouseleave", function() {
    if (!$("#content1").is(":hover"))
    $("#content1").fadeOut(); //hide();
});

$("#box2, #content2").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $("#content2").slideDown(); //.show();
})
.on("mouseleave", function() {
    if (!$("#content2").is(":hover"))
    $("#content2").fadeOut(); //hide();
});
    });
</script>

<div id="buttons">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="content">content here</div>
  <div id="box1"></div>
  <div id="content1">content here</div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
  <div id="content2">content here</div>
</div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

add your jquery functions inside [document.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)